# Handlebar.java Partial names as variables

Tags: handlebars.js

I am trying to include Handlebar.js partials in terms of names, where based on request I can change which partial to include in Handlebar.java on the server side.

For eg.,

Parent page :

```
   --SOME HTML---
   {{> navigation }}
```

I have 3 types of navigation based on request

```
  /customer/navigation.hbs
    /admin/navigation.hbs
    /client/navigation.hbs
```

When I see the code I can see TemplateBuilder.visitPartial includes directly the 
 {{> navigation }} , "navigation" as template path during Template object creation   part. I also tried setting partialHelper with registerHelpers method.

But the code in Partial.merge tries to load the path which was already set during the visitPartial call. Is there anyway to set something like

> navigation =  /admin/navigation.hbs

and apply the template.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the solution in https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/handlebarsjava/qE03NDOkfCg

I did .

```
IncludeHelper iHelper=new IncludeHelper();
handlebars.registerHelper("include", iHelper);
handlebars.compile("/layouts/default")
```

and default.hbs has,

```
{{> navigation }} replaced with {{include navigation }}
```